# TypeORM - can't get value from ManyToOne relatioship

Tags: node.js, database, orm, typeorm

This is the entities I defined:

```
@Entity()
export class InvestorCategory extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  public value: string;

  @Exclude()
  @OneToMany(() => Contract, (entity) => entity.investor_category)
  public contracts: Contract[];
}

@Entity()
export class Contract extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => InvestorCategory, (entity) => entity.contracts)
  public investor_category: InvestorCategory;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public comment: string;
}
```

When it comes to the database, the foreign key is present in the database in the **contract** table, column **investorCategoryId** and when I create and save a new **contact** this column is populated with the proper id.

But when I try doing something along these lines (and TypeScript hints these values):

```
contract?.investor_category
contract?.investor_category?.id
```

I get an **undefined** value.

Is there a step I am missing? Or something wrong with the code? Should I use something like **QueryBuilder** instead?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention - this is the way I get the **contract** from the database:

```
const contract = await this.contractRepository.findOne({where: { id } });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://typeorm.io/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations) - I should have specified a **relations** field in the **FindOptions**.

Example:

```
const userRepository = dataSource.getRepository(User)
const users = await userRepository.find({
    relations: {
        photos: true,
    },
})
```

This probably acts as a join in the SQL query.

I didn't test this yet, but this is most likely the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a workaround - using TypeORM's **Query Builder**

```
const user = await this.userRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('user')
        .innerJoinAndSelect('user.contract', 'contract')
        .innerJoinAndSelect(
          'contract.investor_category',
          'investor_category',
        )
        .where('user.id = :id', { id })
        .getOne();
```

This does not answer why the first solution didn't work, but provides a working solution